# Redirect crontab stdout to stdout instead of default email

Tags: shell, cron, stdout

By default crontab jobs stdout is sent to the email of the crontab user like the crontab file says in the description:

```
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
```

I want to use [slacktee](https://github.com/coursehero/slacktee) same as using (`tee`) to post a message to slack inside the script run by crontab.
In other scripts (daily scheduled by putting them in `/etc/cron.daily/` directory) I do this:

```
echo "New message!" | slacktee -i "tada" -c "messages"
```

And when they run, there are no issues. But in my custom scheduled script I see no message on slack though they run correctly.

My job starts every four hours with this scheduling:

```
* */4 * * * /scripts/mysql_backup.sh
```

I've tried many redirecting (inside the script, inside the cron command) but anything seems working.

How can I use slacktee inside my custom sheduled script?

EDIT:

I'm a bit late sorry for that and thanks for all your time.

@PhilDenfer no, slacktee does not log anything on /tmp.
@Gedge i've tried `sudo echo "test" | slacktee.sh` and it works. Also using `su` and then doing `echo "test" | slacktee.sh` works.
@isp-zax cron jobs runs successfully because the script makes the backup of the database.

Redirecting the stderr I got `slacktee.sh command not found`. So using slacktee.hs as root works but not when root uses it in crontab scheduled job (in a daily scheduled script i use slacktee successfully). Why?

Comment: "*But inside a script run by a crontab job all the stdout is sent to the email of the crontab user, so slacktee doesn't post anything on slack.*" This part makes no sense. Why would redirecting stdout prevent posting on slack?

Comment: Probably it is my wrong belief but I think it's the reason why slacktee does not work. slacktee expect the input  through the pipe and crontab stdout is redirected to the user email

Comment: crontab may redirect output, but its output is the output of all of the commands run in "mysql_backup.sh". echo's output gets redirected to a pipe _before_ its output is sent to crontab. If you have multiple pipes on the same line like so : "a | b | c", output of a only goes to input of b, output of b goes to input of c, and output of c goes to stdout, or may be redirected.
Does slacktee output logs? According to its Github repo, it outputs logs to /tmp, could you check if any line of logs is written when called by you, then when called by crontab with the same user and environment as you?

Comment: Is the output send to `stdout` or to `stderr`? Try something like `/scripts/mysql_backup.sh 1>~/mysql_backup.stdout 2>~/mysql_backup.stderr` and look at the files. If the messages are send to stderr, than `/scripts/mysql_backup.sh 2>&1 | slacktee -i "tada" -c "messages"` should work (the `2>&1` redirects the `stderr`-output to `stdout`).

Comment: Are you running the cron job as the correct user? If user `foo` has the credentials for `slacktee`, but `root` runs the script, then it won't be able to post as `foo` (do you need a _user_ column in the cron.daily script?)

Comment: Agree with Gedge: if using root crontab, make sure your slacktee works when run as root from bash, that root has it in his path, etc; inspect error logs and slacktee logs as PhilDenfer suggested and post what appears there upon cron job completion (increase frequency while testing); inspect the mailbox to which the errors from cron job are being sent and if any errors found post those also. How exactly do you come to the conclusion that cron job runs successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Redirecting the stderr I got slacktee.sh command not found. So using slacktee.hs as root works but not when root uses it in crontab scheduled job (in a daily scheduled script i use slacktee successfully). Why?

Because the PATH variable for user `root` and for user `cron` are different.

Instead of just 'slacktee' use a full path, i.e. `/usr/local/bin/slacktee` and it should work OK.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you all for your help